# Still... missing $_FILES[image]

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, upload

I have this script to upload array of image. Im using simple
`<input type=file name=image[] />`
This script suppose to be able to upload array of multiple images.

Test it and it works fine with my development laptop, i uploaded it to my server and it is not working. The server can only accept the first image I upload. How do I know? I create a script that just contain `print_r($_FILES)`

This is the snipped result of my print_r

```
Array
(
    [image] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => img001.jpg
                    [1] => 
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                    [1] => 
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /tmp/phpFtBfBA
                    [1] => 
                )
        [error] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
                [1] => 4
            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [0] => 4298
                [1] => 0
            )
        )
```

)

View source, copy & paste to another pc, but upload the image to same server and it works again.

I check all the 'same' issue in STACKOVERFLOW and im sure it is not the server because the server can accept images upload if i post it from somewhere else.

On the client side (HTML), I check the enctype=multipart/form-data , close the '/>' for the input  but still have the missing $_FILES.

Thanks in advance

Comment: your field should be.. `<input type="file" name="image[]" multiple="multiple">`

Comment: Check if your `<form>` has multipart. Example: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Added multiple=multiple but still no improvement...

But even without 'multiple', the same script works fine if i put the html from other server (windows)..

i really suspected the html file is the cause... Maybe somehow the html generated is modified..

Comment: Yes Apoorv, my <form> has enctype="multipart/form-data" ... i even tried ENCTYPE=MULTIPART/FORM-DATA .. just to make sure.. but same missing $_FILES happened

Comment: Your `print_r()` output is missing the `error` key, which is probably the most interesting from the debug point of view. I suppose it's actually there and you've just omitted it when posting here. Can you please edit the question and share the complete array?

Comment: Sorry @ÁlvaroGonzález .. didnt notice your comment because its hidden under the 'show 1 more comment' button :)

Yup there is the error key in the array... i didnt paste it assuming everybody get the general idea what the output like... (array 0 have datas, array 1 are blanks)

but i found the cause of my issue (answer below)

Updating my posting (display complete array)... Thanks

Comment: 4 is UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE what means that the server did not even receive the file. You can use the browser console ("Net" pane or equivalent) to verify exactly what's being sent.

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem .. just want to share how i solve it.
Hint: thanks to console .. doesnt notice how error can affect other script..

1. My colleague are using few external js, and doesnt show any error.
2. Using developer console, i found out there's fatal error in the js which affect my input form. [taken pic from web console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoJVS.png)
3. Delete the line that refering to that bad js. It works again..! :-D
4. (After delete the line that call external js, the html still okay.. wondering if they really needed the js :)
5. Now i can sleep .. thanks both of you.